# Access values returned by Woocommerce and Advanced Custom Fields PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I can't seem to access the values being returned by a Repeater relationship field in Advanced Custom Fields.

This is the data structure that is being returned:

```
array(1) {
 ["authors_book"]=>
   array(1) {
    [0]=>
     int(11244)
   }
}
```

And I am trying to access the integer value of 11244

This is how I'm trying:

```
      // Check rows exists.
      if( have_rows('authors_books')):
       
         foreach($authorBooks as $book) :
           // when I debug $book it tells me its an Array    
           $first_row = $book[0];
           echo '<pre>';
           echo var_dump($book); <= prints the data structure above
           echo $book; <= prints out Array
           echo $book[0];  <= prints nothing
           echo var_dump($book[0]); <= prints NULL
           echo $first_row; <= prints nothing
           echo '</pre>';
        endforeach;
        // No value.
        else :
        echo ' there were no books found';
    endif;
```

I don't understand if `$book` is an array, why can't I access the value using `$book[0]`?

Comment: change `$book[0]` to `$book['authors_book'][0]`

Comment: Thanks. That's it exactly.   The parent object is also called 'authors_book' so I think that's what threw me.

Answer (score 1):

As of the given code above, you are using the **have_rows function**, which is meant for looping through a Repeater field, not a relationship field. To learn more about relationship fields, [check out ACF Documentation.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/)

Try this, it may help you get what you wanted!

```
// Get the relationship field value
$authorBooks = get_field('authors_books');

// Check if the field is not empty
if( $authorBooks ):

    // Loop through the array of post IDs
    foreach( $authorBooks as $bookID ):

        // Get the post object for each ID
        $book = get_post($bookID);

        // Display the post title
        echo $book->post_title;

    endforeach;

else :

    // No value
    echo ' there were no books found';

endif;
```

If you find the results with any other way please share here. Thanks!